Can an user go on the parent's folder from the domain pointing index?
I have a simple question that I don't know the answer and difficult to explain in a single title.
Imagine I have this server :
HOME
-- SITE1
---- CSS
------ style.css
---- IMG
-- SITE2
---- CSS
---- PHP
------ index.php

Now, imagine I own example.com and this point to HOME/SITE1, so:

www.example.com/CSS/style.css

will open the css file, but there is a way to go back to home/ and then go to HOME/SITE2 using the domaine example.com ? For example example.com/../SITE2/PHP/index.php ?
I ask this to know if it's secure to get personnal files on my webserver to use it as a cloud for my videos, as I have "unlimited disk space",
Thanks in advance

(excuse me if my english is not clear or my english is bad, it's quite difficult to explain and i'm not english)
